# Python Dict create to own list and add all values with specific Keys in one line

Tags: python

I have a Loop and this Dict as output:

`{2.0 : 7, 7.0 : 2}`

the Key should be the same, but the Value changes everytime

now I want to create a variable for every Key in the Dict and add the value for the Key.

```
for k,v in labels.items():
        if k == 2.0:
             cars += v
        elif k == 7.0:
             trucks += v
        else:
            continue
```

is there a way to write this as a one Liner?

the other problem: I want to add the Value to the variable for every Key but if i use the += the Variable isn't assigned yet. Do i need to define it before or is there a better way to do it?

Comment: `create a variable for every Key in the Dict` - IMO, this requirement indicates something fundamentally wrong in your design. Why would you want to create a different variable for each key? How would you then use this result (results) in order to implement the rest of your plan? You'd need to handle different variables from that moment onwards.

Comment: You can use defaultdict to initialize not existing keys with some value instead of throwing KeyError.

Comment: Why not just make `cars` and `trucks` keys in your dictionary? instead of 2 and 7? Also, what is the use of the FOR loop, why not just access labels[2.0] and labels[7.0] directly?  cars = labels[2.0]; trucks = labels[7.0]

Comment: @bbbbbbbbb so i want to use it to differ the Keys and Values. So the Programm is for Object Detection and I have the different classes for the labels. Currently the Labels just prints the Number for every detected Object in a Dict and how many of them. Thats why I want to use different variables like cars or truck to differ them and add every value of them in that variable to calculate after that

Comment: @matszwecja you mean from Collections the DefaultDict?

Comment: @JeffUK probably i don't need the name Cars and Trucks but just for the Clarification for me. If it's better and more efficient i would just use the 2.0 and 7.0 as variable name

Comment: @Arthi yes, for example you can do `d = defaultdict(lambda: 0); d["cars"] += 10`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's what I'd do for a flexible code that easily handles adding other classes

```
from collections import Counter

labels = {2.0 : 7, 7.0 : 2}

class_mappings = {2.0: "cars", 7.0: "trucks"}

counts = Counter({v:labels[k] for k, v in class_mappings.items()})
```

In case you want to add other values to the counts later on:

```
new_labels = {2.0: 15, 7.0: 5}

for k, v in class_mappings.items():
    counts[v] += new_labels.get(k, 0)
```

Or using the Counter built-in `update` (it works differently than standard `dict.update`):

```
counts.update({v:new_labels[k] for k, v in class_mappings.items()})
```

EDIT: thanks to @tzaman suggestion of using Counter it can be turned into pretty much a one liner.

Comment: I'd use `collections.Counter` here instead of `defaultdict`, but apart from that this is the way to go.

Comment: @tzaman thanks, with Counter it is as compact as it reasonably should be

Comment: @matszwecja thank you for the quick response! But what if the Labels Dict is Changing the Values for Example `{2.0: 15, 7.0: 5}` . How could i add that to the already defined counts with `cars: 7, trucks: 2` that the new output would be `cars: 22, trucks: 7` ?

Comment: @Arthi the version without counter actually showed that better, but I added code that will not overwrite the previous counter.

Answer (score 2):

Your dictionary is called *labels* and may contain keys of 2.0 and 7.0

Therefore (although not a one-liner):

```
cars += labels.get(2.0, 0)
trucks += labels.get(7.0, 0)
```

Comment: what does the 0 stands for? and if i use your code the += throws the unbound error but it's better than the For loop! Thanks for that!

Comment: The unbound error will be because either labels, cars or trucks are not in scope - i.e., you need to fix your code. The second argument to get() is what will be returned if the key is not found